# Overwrite text file between parameters [ and ]

Tags: vb.net

I would like for example to modify in the text file only what is written between [newtext] 103 and [endtext] 103 , from my textbox.

```
[newtext]101
This is a first demonstration
This is a message
of Hello World
[endtext]101

[newtext]102
This is a 2nd demonstration
This is a 2nd message
of Hello World
[endtext]102

[newtext]103
This is a 3nd demonstration
This is a 3nd message
of Hello World
[endtext]103
```

so if I have text in my textbox

```
This is a newest demonstration
This is a newest message
of Hello World
```

how do I adapt to replace file the old text with the new text? that is, the output will be:
attention, the other values between `[newtext] 101, [newtext] 102`, will not be erase.

```
[newtext]103
This is a newest demonstration
This is a newest message
of Hello World
[endtext]103
```

this is a code, but unfortunately it has to find the values ​​between the chosen parameters.

```
Dim text As String = File.ReadAllText(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + ("\Data.txt"))
text = text.Replace(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text)
File.WriteAllText("Data.txt", text)
```

Comment: Are you stuck with this eccentric data format, or are you free to use something else? It would be a lot simpler to use something like JSON or XML to store your data.

Comment: this is a notepad with its own functions based on the listbox with separate topics + separate messages

Comment: Ok. That's a bit vague and I'm not really sure how it's relevant? What notepad? What listbox? All you've shown us is a textbox and a strange data format being stored in a file. Can you answer the question directly please - why are you using this particular data format? If you can change it for something sane, it would be a good idea to do so.

Comment: I don't think that such a data storage can be done differently (separate topic in one corner (listbox1), message in another corner (listbox2), plus search function and subject change.

Comment: File format aside, think what you might be looking for is the String.IndexOf() method(s)https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-5.0  Using that you can find the start and end of the required tags, then replace everything in between as required.  Might also want to read up on Regex which has some methods that might help

Comment: `I don't think that such a data storage can be done differently`...really? You don't think JSON would be a better format? Then you can have each item in a different property. And it's easy to encode and decode it using existing libraries. (It's still unclear how this relates to listboxes, btw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ReadAllLines` returns an array of the lines in the text file. The get the index of the line with the search text. Then get an array of the lines in the `TextBox1`. Simply assign the new text to the proper indexes in the lines in the file. Lastly, I displayed the new string `TextBox2`.

Be sure that both text boxes are wide enough to display the lines and have Multiline = True.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim FileLines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Desktop\Code\DemoMessage.txt")
    Dim lineToFind = "[newtext]103"
    Dim index = Array.IndexOf(FileLines, lineToFind)
    Dim tbLines = TextBox1.Lines
    FileLines(index + 1) = tbLines(0)
    FileLines(index + 2) = tbLines(1)
    FileLines(index + 3) = tbLines(2)
    TextBox2.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, FileLines)
    'you can write the contents of TextBox2 back to file if needed.
End Sub
```